# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delegate')

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning [Azure Devops UI DropDown Component](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/dropdown), and all code are same as sample. After run **npm start**, and to option it, throw an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delegate')
> [image]
> [image]

Below it's my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "azure-devops-ui/Dropdown";
import { IListBoxItem } from "azure-devops-ui/ListBox";
import { Observer } from "azure-devops-ui/Observer";
import { ObservableValue } from "azure-devops-ui/Core/Observable";

export default class BasicDropdownExample extends React.Component {
    private selectedItem = new ObservableValue<string>("");

    public render() {
        return (
            <div className="flex-row" style={{ margin: "8px", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Dropdown
                    ariaLabel="Basic"
                    className="example-dropdown"
                    placeholder="Select an Option"
                    items={[
                        { id: "item1", text: "Item 1" },
                        { id: "item2", text: "Item 2" },
                        { id: "item3", text: "Item 3" }
                    ]}
                    onSelect={this.onSelect}
                />
                <Observer selectedItem={this.selectedItem}>
                    {(props: { selectedItem: string }) => {
                        return (
                            <span style={{ marginLeft: "8px", width: "150px" }}>
                                Selected Item: {props.selectedItem}{" "}
                            </span>
                        );
                    }}
                </Observer>
            </div>
        );
    }

    private onSelect = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, item: IListBoxItem<{}>) => {
        this.selectedItem.value = item.text || "";
    };
}
```

This error looks like from **Dropdown** reload. This **onSelect** function is running well.
[image]

I try to search about React ObserverBase questions, but these don't work for me.